# Django csrf token not refreshed after first login

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-csrf

I have hosted a website at http://cognezic-dev.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/login/. On closer inspection, the form has the same csrf token across page refreshes and browsers, which I suspect to be the cause of the issue,this works fine on the local django server.Dont know where this is being cached. I have added CSRF Middleware in the settings.py too.
You can use the test credentials as username bismeet and password bis12345 for testing.
I have also tried creating a custom middleware as follows:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token, CsrfViewMiddleware
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class CSRFRefresh(CsrfViewMiddleware,MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        print("Custom MiddleWare called")
        rotate_token(request)
        return response
```

But it still fails.

My settings.py with custom middleware contains:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
     'solvesto.middleware.csrf_refresh.CSRFRefresh'
]
```

If not using the custom middleware,I use:

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'
```

instead of

```
'solvesto.middleware.csrf_refresh.CSRFRefresh'
```

The only last resort I see to make this work is to remove csrf altogether,which is of course,bad for security.

Comment: Why do you call `rotate_token` on the middleware? And you don't even call `super`!! The `process_response` is supposed to set the CSRF cookie on the response... Also add your `MIDDLEWARE` setting to the question. And do you use the `cache_page` decorator anywhere in your code?

Comment: Should I call super? Couldn't see it in the docs. Also, why doesn't it work without a custom middleware? No, I haven't used the cache_page decorator.

Comment: You have written this custom middleware for some reason. Looking at your implementation it will surely break things. It should work without a custom middleware. Please add your `MIDDLEWARE` list to the question.

Comment: Added the line with the middleware contents to the question.

Comment: Well, I have removed the csrf in order to make it work,no other way that I can think of, kindly let me know if you have  a better solution.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Could you help with the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the csrf security,no other solution,works now.